# Property of a semiring equipped with partial order relation

Tags: order-theory, semiring, ordered-rings

Let $R$ be a multiplicatively idempotent semiring with  additive identity, and a partial order relation $\leq$ is defined on $R$. Then, for all $x$ in $R$, does the identity $x+2x=2x$ implies $x\leq 2x$?.

I think the last line will hold if second last line holds. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample**. Let $R = (\{0, 1, 2\}, \oplus, \otimes)$ be the semiring defined by $x \oplus y = \min \{x + y, 2\}$ and $x \otimes y = \min \{xy, 2\}$.
Then $R$ is multiplicatively idempotent and the equality is a partial order relation on $R$. However $1 \oplus (1 \oplus 1) = (1 \oplus 1)$ but $1 \not= 1 \oplus 1$.

Comment: Please revisit the fourth line of my post. It is inequality, but not equality. Moreover, $1\leq 1\oplus 1$ which is an example satisfying my problem, but not a counter example.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but in my example the relation $\leqslant$ is the equality relation, so that $x \leqslant y$ if and only if $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. By the ways, it seems very difficult to find other counter examples (other than equality relation). I mean will it will be true if we exclude equality relation?

Comment: Do you want your partial order be compatible with addition and multiplication?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: You may take the product of my semiring $R$ with the Boolean semiring ordered by $0 \leqslant 1$ and take $x = (1, 0)$.

Comment: That's nice. Thank you

Comment: J.-E. Pin  Please carefully study this meta.math.se post: [Enforcement of Quality STandards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which, in part, puts answerers responsible for **not** answering very poor questions without context.

Comment: @amWhy I read this post several times before answering this question and I am so unsatisfied with its current version that I may consider not answering questions on this site anymore.